# Multi VM Create using ansible playbook from Templates

Tags: ansible, vmware, build-automation, vsphere

Problem Statement:
while trying to create a VM from a template especially in the case of a windows OS template(working fine for linux OS template). VM after being created through ansible playbook is "powered off".

Here is my playbook to create  multiple VMS from template, please help me in making this playbook more efficient...thanks in advance.

```
---
- name: Create a multiple VMs asynchronously
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no  
  tasks:
  - name: Clone the template
    vmware_guest:
      hostname: xxx.xxx.xx
      username: username
      password: password
      validate_certs: False
      name: "{{ item }}"
      template: Template-Win-2016
      cluster: cluster
      datacenter: Dev and QA DC
      folder: /
      state: poweredon
      hardware:
          memory_mb: 12288
          num_cpus: 4
      disk:
        - size_gb: 60
          type: thin
          autoselect_datastore: True
      wait_for_ip_address: yes 
    with_items:
      - testvm001
      - testvm002
    register: vm_create
    async: 600
    poll: 0
    

  - name: Waiting for status
    async_status:
      jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
    register: job_result
    until: job_result.finished
    delay: 60
    retries: 60
    with_items: "{{ vm_create.results }}"
```

Comment: This could be causes by the 'golden image' used for windows VM, have you check manually this image (provide just a VM and see what happend, and get which event powererd off the instanve if possible on windows event)

Comment: I have a similar playbook but i dont have to define cpu disk because we have it in the template of the windows and also running a template of customization, my vms created in powerdon state